# how do i disable a back button only if and if and only the previous router pathname is 'Login' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

this is the type of back button that is used to navigate to the previous pages, rather than using the navigation bar but I now want to disable it when the next previous route inline is 'login'

[image]

I've read other questions on this platform and tried this but it seems like it's not the right logic

```
    const handleGoBack = () => {
      if (authStatus) {
            window.history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
            window.onpopstate = function (event) {
            window.history.go(1);
          };
         return window.history.back()
       };
     };
```

I doubt if there is such a thing but I want something of this nature

```
     const handleGoBack = ( e, authStatus ) => {
       if(previouseRouter === 'login')
          return authStatus && event.currentTarget.disabled === true
     }
```

is there a better way to tackle the problem.. and also I'm using Hashrouter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of check if previous router was `Login`, you could navigate from Login to the next page using `history.replace("path/to/next/page")`. In this way you replace last navigation history and goBack does not falls into Login page.

Comment: I'm getting this error 

`Warning: Cannot update a component (`Dispenseware`) while rendering a different component (`Login`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Login`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render`

Comment: @Chirume Yes I understand your problem but without code is really hard to say where the problem is. Could you post some `Login` and `Dispenseware` components code?

Comment: my code is too much but I get the concept behind it though thanks a lot. if I'm not mistaken its the same as the one shown [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow)

Comment: I managed to resolve the component update while rendering error by passing the `history.replace('path/to/next/page')` as  a callback `authenticate(loginDetails, () => history.replace('/'));`